# Can't add button from Toolbox to Navigation Item in Visual Studio for the Mac

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios

I'm having trouble dragging a button (for +) onto the Navigation item of a master view controller in a project that uses Storyboards.  I have no problem in Visual Studio for the PC, but recently switched to **Visual Studio for the Mac** and its not working.  This is simple and I must be dense.  Help!!!

Comment: Drag button into NavigationBar , am i right ?I tried on both windows and mac, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used VS for mac's built-in interface editor for once. Right click on the storyboard file(in vs for mac) from there "Open with" > "xcode Interface Builder". VS for mac syncs your changes when you save what you have done in xcode. I haven't faced any problems with this approach.

Comment: Wow!  That worked.  VS for PC works just like Xcode, but VS for Mac doesn't seem to support this specific drag/drop!

Thanks!